# IIS Log Parser - Need Query to find "total requests taking > x secs" / "Total Requests" grouped by URL

Tags: iis, logging, logparser

I am supporting an application that is having occasional performance issues. The client wants to know how often a page is slow.

i.e. Total times a page took greater than x secs / Total number of requests for the page

I would like to write a single query to fetch the desired data.

Something like this in SQL would probably work but isn't working in IIS Log parser.

```
select URL, count(case when time > 100  then 1 else null end), count(*)
from   table1
group by URL
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that you need two queries.

- One to count the total number of requests per page regardless of time taken

  ```
  SELECT cs-uri-stem, COUNT(*) AS all-requests 
  FROM ex*.log 
  GROUP BY cs-uri-stem
  ```
- One to count the number of pages where time-taken > X seconds

  ```
  SELECT cs-uri-stem, COUNT(*) as total-requests
  FROM ex*.log
  WHERE time-taken > 1000 <- time_taken is milliseconds
  GROUP BY cs-uri-stem
  ```

The result you're after would require a JOIN:

```
SELECT a.cs-uri-stem, COUNT(*) as total-requests, b.all-requests
FROM ex*.log AS a
JOIN (
    SELECT cs-uri-stem, COUNT(*) AS all-requests 
    FROM ex*.log 
    GROUP BY cs-uri-stem
) AS b ON b.cs-uri-stem = a.cs-uri-stem
WHERE a.time-taken >1000 
GROUP BY a.cs-uri-stem
```

Unfortunately there is no support for JOIN's in LogParser.

What you could do is import the results of both queries into a SQL Database and run the query there:

```
SELECT a.cs-uri-stem, COUNT(*) as total-requests, b.all-requests
FROM long_running_pages AS a
JOIN all_pages_grouped b ON ( a.cs-uri-stem = b.cs-uri-stem)
GROUP BY a.cs-uri-stem
```